# Firebase: Proper database filter on newData

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning how `firebase` database filters work, and i haven't get a clue on other answers as to how this really works, i have also been reading the docs to see if i could understand it's whole functionality but yet i cannot get my goal (probably i am reading the wrong section)

I have a simple document to insert in the database as follows:

```
{
  "name": "new project"
}
```

right now i want to apply rules for `name` to validate if it is a number just for testing (upon figuring this out, i will set more complex conditions). So i have made a simple database rule structure for this scenario:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
      "projects": {
        "$project": {
          "name": {
            ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"  // also tried newData.child('name').isNumber()
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

if i understood this right `$project` is the id of the new document to insert and will have the values passed on the inserting document.

I have been using the rule simulator to check on my progress of the rules but everytime i try this with a different code it always go on `Simulated write allowed` as long as i am authenticated.

So again, how can i apply the rules for the newData.prop in order to set the database a secure schema?

Comment: Can you show the operation that you're trying to perform, which is rejected by the simulator?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Everything i tried is already posted

Comment: "I have been using the rule simulator to check on my progress of the rules..." I want to see what you tried that failed. Without seeing that, it'll be hard for me to help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i just noticed that the only thing making a success validation is ".write" and therefore the rest is not even taken under consideration

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. If you say that writing works as long as you are authenticated, then you're rules work perfectly. That's what ".write": "auth != null" does.